# How to concatenate a tf.Variable to achieve Mahalanobis regularization in the loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to define a loss in tensorflow, which contains a regularization term. However, this is not the standard l2 or l1 norm. This is a Mahalanobis norm on the weights, with a covariance matrix P.

For example, let's say I have a neural net with two layers which contains the following weights (tf.Variables): W1, b1, W2, b2. In order to calculate the Mahalanobis norm I need to concatenate all the weights into one vector, let's call it "theta" where theta=[W1(:), b1(:), W2(:), b2(:)]^T. Then I want to perform "theta^T P theta".

My question is: How do I change the shape of a tf.Variable, while keeping the following properties:

1. The loss contains tf.variables which have 2 representations: One representation of 2-D tensors (W1, b1, W2, b2, inside the neural network) and another representation as a concatenate vector theta (in the regularization term). For example, the weights inside W1 appear both in the 2-D tensor W1 and also inside theta.
2. The minimizer should "know" that when it calculates the gradient with respect to the  weights (W1, b1, W2, b2), it should take into consideration the 2 representations of the weight as explained above.

I add some code to illustrate my question. How do I define "theta" as a concatenated vector of (W1, b1, W2, b2), with the properties mentioned above?

I searched for answers to my question, but all the regularizations I saw were l2 or l1 norms on the weights, and not something that requires a concatenation of the weights, as in my case.

Thanks!

```
    def create_model_trainable(self):
    """
    Defines the trained network
    :return:
    """

    self.q_values = self.neural_net(self.input_placeholder)
    self.selected_q = tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(self.q_values, self.actions_placeholder), 1)
    theta = ???
    covariance = self.create_covariance_parameters()
    regularization = self.regularization(covariance, theta)
    self.loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(self.labels_placeholder - self.selected_q)) + regularization
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    self.train_op = optimizer.minimize(self.loss)

def neural_net(self, input_obs):
    """
    Defines the architecture of the neural network.
    :param input_obs: input_placeholder for inputs
    :return:
            out: tf Tensor of full structure of the network
    """
    with tf.name_scope("Layer1"):
        W1shape = [self.observation_shape, self.hidden_size]
        W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=W1shape)
        b_shape = [1, self.hidden_size]
        b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", shape=b_shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

    with tf.name_scope("OutputLayer"):
        Ushape = [self.hidden_size, self.num_actions]
        U = tf.get_variable("U", shape=Ushape)
        b3shape = [1, self.num_actions]
        b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", shape=b3shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

    xW = tf.matmul(input_obs, W1)
    h = tf.tanh(tf.add(xW, b1))

    hU = tf.matmul(h, U)
    out = tf.add(hU, b3)
    return out
```